# Java Sound transmission over UDP - Sound errors when implementing input level checking method

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, udp, voip

i'm writing a program for simple voice transmission via udp. This works fine, until I implement a method to check the average volume level of a sample-to-be-sent.

Here I have included the Audio class and the Receiver class and cut out some unimportant stuff.

```
public class Audio extends Thread
{
    private AudioFormat defaultAudioFormat = null;
    private TargetDataLine inputLine = null;
    private byte[] sample = new byte[1024];
    private SourceDataLine speakers = null;
    private int voiceActivationLevel = 35;
    private SourceDataLine speakers = null;
    private boolean running = true;
    private VOIPSocket sender = null;
    
    public Audio(int voiceActivationLevel, VOIPSocket socket) throws LineUnavailableException
    {
        this.voiceActivationLevel = voiceActivationLevel;
        this.defaultAudioFormat = new AudioFormat(8000f, 16, 1, true, true);
        
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, this.defaultAudioFormat);
        this.inputLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        this.inputLine.open(defaultAudioFormat);
        this.sender = socket;
        
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, this.defaultAudioFormat);
        this.speakers = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        this.speakers.open();
        this.speakers.start();
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        DataLine.Info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, this.defaultAudioFormat);
        this.inputLine.start();
        while(running)
        {
            if(AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info))
            {
                int data = inputLine.read(this.sample, 0, sample.length);
                int voiceLevel = calculateVolumeLevel(this.sample);
                if(voiceLevel >= this.voiceActivationLevel)
                    this.sender.sendData(this.sample); //
            }
        }
    }
    
    public int calculateVolumeLevel(byte[] audioData)
    {
        long l = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < audioData.length; i++)
            l = l + audioData [i];
        double avg = l / audioData.length;
        double sum = 0d;
        
        for(int j = 0; j < audioData.length; j++)
            sum += Math.pow(audioData[j] - avg, 2d);
        
        double averageMeanSquare = sum / audioData.length;
        return (int)(Math.pow(averageMeanSquare, 0.5d) + 0.5);
    }
    
    public void playSound(byte[] data)
    {
        synchronized(this.speakers)
            this.speakers.write(data, 0, data.length);
    }
}
```

Note that calculateVolumeLevel does NOT modify voiceData, just returns an average volume level as integer.

```
public class Receiver extends Thread
{
    private VOIPSocket socket = null; //Just a simple class with some helper functions for the socket, not important for this
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private Audio audio = null;
    
    public Receiver(VOIPSocket socket, Audio audio) throws SocketException
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.audio = audio;
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(this.buffer, this.buffer.length);
        while(isRunning)
        {
            if(!socket.getSocket.isClosed())
            {
                socket.getSocket.receive(packet);
                byte data = packet.getData();
                this.audio.playSound(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I include the check for the volume level, the sound is stuttering, repeating over and over and other mistakes, until I flush or drain the speakers-dataline.

The data transmission via UDP is working correctly and needs no further investigation in my opinion.

My read is, that as soon as I implement check for the voice volume, the byte-data somehow is corrupted or important parts of sample[] are not transmitted. This somehow puts errors on the speakers-dataline.

I don't know how to solve this. Any ideas?

edit:

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/troubleshoot/java-sound.htm#JSTGD490, some over- or underrun condition comes in I guess.
If I dont have the volume check enabled, a continuous data stream is provided for the speakers-dataline. If it is enabled, this stream of course is interrupted most of the time, leading to corrupted data in either the input dataline or the speakers-dataline (or both).
This can be solved by flushing and closing the datalines, then opening them again. This unfortunately is not a suitable solution, as flushing can sometimes take up to 1 second, where no data can be played, which is not acceptable, as I would need to flush very often (like every time, there is silence).

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Declare `l` as a double instead of a long.  `l / audioData.length` is integer math, because both sides are exact values (as opposed to floating-point values).  Although you are assigning the result of that operation to a double, the operation itself truncates its result before the assignment is made.

Comment: VGR's suggestion is valid, but if it does not solve your problem, try this: `if(voiceLevel >= this.voiceActivationLevel) this.sender.sendData(this.sample); else this.sender.sendData(EMPTY);` Of course I am not suggesting that you transmit empty packets, but if it does solve the problem, then you know where to look for a fix.

Comment: Also, your volume level checking function looks very expensive. Have you tried invoking the function but then sending the data regardless of the outcome of the function? If the problem persists, then you know that it is the poor performance of that function which is causing the problem.

Comment: You have multithreading here - as you correctly indicated - so anything can  garble  your data. You don't have a single actor and without the data locked it's up for grabs! If you want to store your data  at your own storage and then send it be my guest. And plus TargetLine does not guarantee anything READ the Docs.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice so far.
Unfortunately, VGR and Nakis' approaches did not solve the problem
According to gpasch, I checked the docs for java sound api more.
And here seems the problem: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/troubleshoot/java-sound.htm#JSTGD490

I thin overrun and underrun conditions are involved in this. As soon as the speakers Dataline is not receiving anymore data, some kind of over- or underrun happens, corrupting the data as described in the article. So I need to find a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider buffering the volume-checking. For example, I wrote a line that takes input from a live microphone's `TargetDataLine`, converts to PCM and passes the data on to an input track of an audio mixing tool. The key to getting this to work in my situation was providing an intermediate, concurrent-safe FIFO queue. I used a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Float[]>` with the float[] arrays holding signed, normalized float "packets" of PCM.

A more experienced coder than myself used to continuously harp on the following general principle in working with audio: avoid locks. I haven't read through the code you provided thoroughly enough to know if this is arising in your case, but seeing the keyword `synchronized` in the `playSound` method reminds me of his advice.

The only blocking when working with audio, I think, should be that which is built into the blocking queues employed by `TargetDataLine` or `SourceDataLine` read and write methods. I blindly pass on this advice and encourage you to inspect your code for blocking and find alternatives in any situation in your code where a block might occur.